# DataViewWebPart XSLT Caching

Tags: performance, xslt, caching, data-view-web-part

I have a DataViewWebPart with a complicated and rather expensive linked XSLT (the XSLT itself is stored in the Documents library of the site).

Currently, the part takes a long time to render, even though I have the cache web part settings configured properly (I think):

```
    <property name="CacheXslTimeOut" type="int">86400</property>
    <property name="CacheXslStorage" type="bool">True</property>
```

**Is there anything else that I need to set to enable XSLT caching?**

**Is there anything that I might be doing inadvertently that would cause the DVWP to re-run the XSLT?**

Answer (score 1):

A solution may be to not use the DVWP cache; instead you could enable the output cache on your page.

Answer (score 1):

I would also suggest placing your XSL file to a file system, to use output cache for your end users. That way only 1st request takes some time to load XSL, all the following requests will use local copy.

Comment: I'm not really sure what this means - can you give me a quick run-down on how you think I would implement this?

Comment: you can put your XSL file  to the 14\Template\Layouts folder on a server (SP feature is preferrable if you want to control it by activation or you have more than one WFE). URL of the XSL will be http://site/_layouts/file.xsl . Ofc you can use subfolder there to have it better organized

Comment: won't the XSLT be picked up by the output cache if it's published in a document library?

Comment: unfortunately no afaik